# Removal of colon and carriage returns and replace with colon

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a project where I have a HMTL fragment which needs to be cleaned up - the HTML has been removed and as a result of table being removed, there are some strange ends where they shouldnt be :-)

the characters as they appear are

1. a space at the beginning of a line
2. a colon, carriage return and linefeed at the end of the line - which needs to be replaced simply with the colon;

I am presently using regex as follows:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(:[\r\n])", ":", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// gets rid of the leading space
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(^[( )])", "", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Example of what I am dealing with:

```
Tomas Adams

Solicitor
APLawyers
p:
1800 995 718
f:
07 3102 9135
a:
22 Fultam Street
 PO Box 132, Booboobawah QLD 4113
```

which should look like:

```
Tomas Adams
Solicitor
APLawyers
p:1800 995 718
f:07 3102 9135
a:22 Fultam Street
PO Box 132, Booboobawah QLD 4313
```

as my attempt to clean the string, but the result is far from perfect ... Can someone assist me to correct the error and achive my goal ...

[EDIT]
the offending characters

```
f:\r\n07 3102 9135\r\na:\r\n22
```

the combination of :\r\n should be replaced by a single colon.

MTIA

Darrin

Comment: can you post a debugger insight screen shot of `s` so that we can see what kind of white spaces characters we are dealing here with?

Comment: FYI `[( )]` matches the character `(`, or `)`, or a space.

Comment: It looks like your multi-line replace should be working with your first expression: http://regexr.com/3vekm

Comment: `:[\r\n]` means `:` followed by either `\r` or `\n`, that's why `:\r\n` will be turned into `:\n`

Comment: Try  `var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?m)^\s+|(?<=:)(?:\r?\n)+|(\r?\n){2,}", "$1")`.

Comment: @Wiktor - thank you for your assistance - fixed the problem as I explained it ... I am a newby here and am trying to work out how to accept your comment as an answer ...

Comment: @DWE you cannot accept a comment as an answer. Wiktor, can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: @DWE Posted with explanations.

Comment: @Wiktor ..Thank you for the assistance - great answer and as ongoing support you referred me to a very instructive website for future  [RegEx reference]: http://regexstorm.net/reference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?m)^\s+|(?<=:)(?:\r?\n)+|(\r?\n){2,}", "$1")
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5Cs%2B%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%3A%29%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%2B%7C%28%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%7B2%2C%7D&i=Tomas%20Adams%0D%0A%0D%0ASolicitor%0D%0AAPLawyers%0D%0Ap%3A%0D%0A1800%20995%20718%0D%0Af%3A%0D%0A07%203102%209135%0D%0Aa%3A%0D%0A22%20Fultam%20Street%0D%0A%20PO%20Box%20132%2C%20Booboobawah%20QLD%204113&r=%241).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - equal to `RegexOptions.Multiline` - makes `^` match the start of any line here
- `^` - start of a line
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `(?<=:)(?:\r?\n)+` - a position that is immediately preceded with `:` (matched with `(?<=:)` positive lookbehind) followed with 1+ occurrences of an optional CR and LF (those are removed)
- `|` - or
- `(\r?\n){2,}` - two or more consecutive occurrences of an optional CR followed with an LF symbol. Only the last occurrence is saved in Group 1 memory buffer, thus the `$1` replacement pattern inserts that last, single, occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution without Regex:

```
var lines = input.Split(new []{"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var output = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].EndsWith(":")) // feel free to also check for the size
    {
        lines[i + 1] =  lines[i] + lines[i + 1];
        continue;
    }
    output.AppendLine(lines[i].Trim()); // remove space before or after a line
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jlGN7J)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your regular expression.I was able to replace "\n" and ":" with the following regular expression.This is removing ":" and "\n" at the end of the line.
 @"([:\r\n])"

Answer (score 0):

A Linq solution without Regex:

```
var tmp = string.Empty;
var output = input.Split(new []{"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a,b) => {
    if (b.EndsWith(":")) {  // feel free to also check for the size
        tmp = b;
    }
    else {
        a.AppendLine((tmp + b).Trim()); // remove space before or after a line
        tmp = string.Empty;
    }
    return a;
});
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/46cGvo)